# Cannot get results from datastore in dialogflow fulfillment hosted in another project - SOLVED

Tags: google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-datastore, dialogflow-es, dialogflow-es-fulfillment

Every Dialogflow chatbot is associated with a project. There are apparently no limits for the number of chatbots that could be created. But the resources that they may use, like fulfillment functions, are billed. Working with a trial account in GCP I can have only 3 billable projects (unless I ask for an upgrade). But nothing denies the use of resources like functions or datastore that are hosted by a billable account by another project. So, I am trying to use an fulfillment function for a chatbot hosted in one of these billable projects. There's no problem. I can invoke the function and it works. But I need to make a query in datastore and it does not work in this context. I ran the same code in another function in the same project and the query results are ok. But the query does not run inside an intent mapped function (function topic(agent) {...}).
Here are the excerpts for these two functions:

(1) Returns query results

```
exports.helloWorld = (req, res) => {

const query = datastore
  .createQuery('Synonym')
  .filter('synonym', "annual salary");
  datastore.runQuery(query, (err, entities, info) => {
  // entities = An array of records.
  // Access the Key object for an entity.
  var message = "<h3>Synonyms for ANNUAL SALARY</h3>";
  for (const entity of entities) {
    const entityKey = entity[datastore.KEY];
    message += entityKey.name + " is synonym of " + entity["synonym"] + "</br>";
  }
  res.status(200).send(message);
});
```

};

returns:

Synonyms for ANNUAL SALARY

annual is synonym of annual salary

annual salary is synonym of annual salary

...

(2) Does not return results

```
exports.HRChatbotFulfillment = functions.https.onRequest((request, response) => {
  const agent = new WebhookClient({ request, response });
 ...

function topic(agent) {
    const topic = agent.parameters['topic'];
    var message = "Synonyms for " + topic + "\n";
    const query = datastore.createQuery('Synonym').filter('synonym', topic);
    datastore.runQuery(query, (err, entities, info) => {
      // entities = An array of records.
      // Access the Key object for an entity.
      for (const entity of entities) {
        const entityKey = entity[datastore.KEY];
        message += entityKey.name + " is synonym of " + entity["synonym"] + "\n";
      }
    });
    agent.add(message);
  }
```

returns:

"Synonyms for annual salary"

Fulfillment status
Webhook execution successful

I will appreciate any suggestions.
Thank you.

*UPDATE*

It takes me some time to figure out how to deal with this asynchronous calls but I've got it:

```
const runQuery = (query) => new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  datastore.runQuery(query,(err, entities, info) => {
  if (err) {
    return reject(err)
  }
  return resolve([entities,info])
  })
});
async function topic(agent) {
  const topic = agent.parameters['topic']; 
  var message = "Synonyms for " + topic.toUpperCase() + "\r\n";
  const query = datastore
    .createQuery('Synonym')
    .filter('synonym', topic);
  try {
    const [entities,info] = await runQuery(query);
    for (const entity of entities)
    {
      const entityKey = entity[datastore.KEY];
      message += entityKey.name + "\r\n";
    }
  }
  catch(err){
    agent.add("Err: " + err);
  } 
  agent.add(message);
}
```

Thank you all for your attention.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! You report that "the query doesn't run", but you don't make it clear why you believe this or provide any error messages that your'e getting when you try to run this code. You also don't make it clear if `topic()` is registered as the Intent Handler, or how (exactly) it is called. Please update your question to show this info, along with any other information that may help us help you.

Comment: Thank you, Prisoner.

`topic()` is registered as an intent handler and it runs when the intent is matched. But it returns only the first line of the variable `message`. No more lines (error, info or query results) are added by the query and it seems that are no errors: "Webhook execution successful".

The same code runs successfully in another function (helloWorld) triggered by an http request and returns the records with `res.status(200).send(message);`

Comment: To better understand this issue, we need to understand what is and more specifically isn’t happening. We need to validate whether the Cloud Function is receiving and parsing the input correctly and if the query is correctly built.

We already know that the output isn’t correct, so we need to see where along the lines it goes off the tracks. Can you add logging details to each part you expect the data to change, so that we can see the bigger picture and help you resolve this issue?

Comment: Thank you. The function receives the request as expected. The handler is called, the parameter is identified but the body of runQuery callback isn't executed. I've tried logging in all parts of the code to check if I've got the objects and function arguments correctly. When it comes to the body of runQuery's callback no line is executed. In another function (first one above) runQuery runs and the function sends the response. I have tried other constructions but nothing results. Function log reports successful execution.

Comment: Solved. Than you.